# Bubble sort program C

Tags: c

Write a function that when invoked as bubble_string(s) causes the characters in the string s to be bubble-sorted. If s contains the string "xylophone", then the following statement should cause ehlnoopxy to be printed.
The errors I get are: 10.4.c: In function `main':
10.4.c:3: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
10.4.c: In function`main':
10.4.c:8: error: syntax error before "char"
10.4.c: In function `bubble_string':
10.4.c:17: error: syntax error before ')' token
10.4.c:18: error: syntax error before ')' token

Any ideas on how to fix this?

### updated

**Code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap (char*, char*);
bubble_string(char s[]);

int main(void)
{
    char *s= "xylophone";
    printf("%s", bubble_string(char *s));

    return 0;
}

bubble_string(char s[])
{
    char i, j, n;
    n  = strlen(s);
    for(i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i)
            for(j = n - 1; j > 0; --j)
                    if(s[j-1] > s[j])
                            swap(&s[j-1], &s[j]);
}
```

Comment: Jacob: You keep editing your question in a way that invalidates the answers you're getting.   Edits are encouraged, but please keep enough of the original context so that the answers you've received still make sense.  Even better, post followup questions if you need more help, rather than using one post and updating it repeatedly in response to the answers you're getting.

Answer (score 1):

Among other problems, you declare that `bubble_string` does not return a value (by giving it return type `void`), then you go on to use it in the `printf` statement as if it returned a value.  (At least that's how it looked before your edit...the way you have it now, it will default to returning an int, but you use it as if it were a string, and you're not actually returning anything from `bubble_string`.)

Also, your `for` loop syntax is way off.  The outer loop should probably be
more like:

`for(i=0; i < n-1; i++) {/* et cetera */}`

Answer (score 0):

Your bubble_string function needs to return a char*. Otherwise it is returning a void to printf, which is causing your error (because printf is expecting a char*).

Answer (score 0):

Your bubble_string( ) function needs to return a char*, if you're using it in a printf( ).

Comment: pointer to char, or char*, not string. C doesn't have strings.

Comment: As a programmer, I don't see a real difference between the two. Obviously the compiler will disagree ;)  Edited for correctness, though.

Comment: Yeah I know what you mean. I just think it's important, especially for newer programmers asking questions, to not get a "string" and a "pointer to char" mixed up. Especially since he's doing C, not C++.